# Upper bound for an expression

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I've been reading a paper and came across the following inequality
$$- \langle B^T B y^k, x^{k+1} - x^k\rangle \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(\|x^{k}-x^{k-1}\|_{B^T B}^2-\|x^{k+1}-x^{k}\|_{B^T B}^2 - \|y^{k}\|_{B^T B}^2\right)$$
where $y^{k}=(x^{k+1}-x^{k})-(x^{k}-x^{k-1})$.

Now instead of $B^T B$, I have a matrix $A$. If $A$ is symmetric positive definite, using Cholesky decomposition, I can get to the same previous expression but I have a matrix $A$ that is not symmetric and have the following form
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0_d & I_d & 0_d & \dots & 0_d & 0_d & 0_d \\
    0_d & 0_d & 0_d & \dots & 0_d & 0_d & 0_d\\
    0_d & I_d & 0_d & I_d & \dots & 0_d & 0_d\\
    0_d & 0_d & 0_d & 0_d & \dots & 0_d & 0_d\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0_d & 0_d & 0_d & \dots & I_d & 0_d & I_d\\
    0_d & 0_d & 0_d & \dots & 0_d & 0_d & 0_d
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
where the even rows of $A$ are equal to the vector whose elements are all zeros, and $0_d$ and $I_d$ denotes the zeros matrix and the identity matrix of order $d$, respectively.

I was trying to derive an upper bound that have a similar form (a bound that is a function of the three terms $\|x^{k}-x^{k-1}\|^2$, $-\|x^{k+1}-x^{k}\|^2$, and $- \|y^{k}\|^2$. Currently, the bound I have is
$$- \langle A y^k, x^{k+1} - x^k\rangle \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(\|A y^k - (x^{k+1}-x^{k})\|^2-\|x^{k+1}-x^{k}\|^2 - \|A y^{k}\|^2\right)$$
and I was trying to express the first term $\|A y^k - (x^{k+1}-x^{k})\|^2$ as a function of the terms $\|x^{k}-x^{k-1}\|^2$ and $-\|x^{k+1}-x^{k}\|^2$ but didn't get through.